# How does $RANDOM work in Unix shells? Looks like a variable but it actually assumes different values each time it's called

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I recently used the `$RANDOM` variable and I was truly curious about the under-the-hood implementation of it: the syntax says it's a variable but the behavior says it's like a function as it returns a different value each time it's called.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit – that's a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not "in Unix shells"; this is a Bash-specific feature.

It's not hard to guess what's going on under the hood; the shell special-cases this variable so that each attempt to read it instead fetches two bytes from a (pseudo-) random number generator.

To see the definition, look at `get_random` in [`variables.c`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/variables.c#1363) (currently around line 1363).

Comment: Is it possible to `export` a variable like this ourselves or is the only example the built-in `$RANDOM`?

Comment: There are a few other "magical" variables like this; another is `SECONDS`. You can't create this sort of special logic from Bash itself, though you could of course modify the source code and make your own version of the shell with additional magical variables.

Answer (score 1):

> about the under-the-hood implementation of it

There are some special "dynamic variables" with special semantics - `$PWD` `$HOME` `$LINENO` etc. When bash gets the value of the variable, it executes a special function.

`RANDOM` "variable" is setup [here bash/variables.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/variables.c#L1917) and [get_random()](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/variables.c#L1383) just sets the value of the variable, taking random from [a simple generator implementation in bash/random.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/lib/sh/random.c#L104).